# My script isn't deleting or destroying my prefab game object in Unity2D

Tags: unity, c#

My script isn't deleting this game object once it reaches a certain position in my game. This is my script:

```
public float left;

public GameObject enemyLeft;

void Start ()
{
    enemyLeft= GameObject.Find("Enemy Left");
}

void Update()
{
    if (transform.position.x < left)
    {
        Destroy (enemyLeft);
    }
}
```

`enemyLeft` is a prefab `gameObject` that is being spawned in by my spawner.

This is the script where I intend to `Destroy` the game object:

```
    public float left;

    public GameObject[] enemiesLeft;

    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < enemiesLeft.Length; i++) {

            if (enemiesLeft[i].transform.position.x < left) {
                Destroy (enemiesLeft[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Why isn't it deleting the game object?

Comment: Please clarify your question. You want to destroy the enemy once the enemy gets to a certain position, or you want to destroy whatever object this script is attached to whenever the enemy reaches a certain position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate position of `enemyLeft` instead of script holding object.

```
   void Update()
    {
        if (enemyLeft.transform.position.x < left)
        {
            Destroy (enemyLeft);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it worked :), what if I wanted to add a number of how many enemies I want to destroy rather than copy and pasting below the code and renaming it. :)

Comment: For shortcut, use array of enemies. `public GameObject[] enemyLeft;` Use a loop to get and check if any of them crossed left position, then destroy. `Destroy (enemyLeft[i]);` You will end up losing objects in array. So should take a long term solution.

Comment: Okay thank you for the reply, I tried out what you said but it doesn't seem to work it doesn't delete anything...again. :(. If you look above I have edit my question and you can see the second edit. Thank you :)

Comment: You are not getting any objects for checking and destroying in the `Start()`. Also get objects with tag instead of name.

Comment: sorry i'm a bit confused

Comment: `enemyLeft = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy Left");` is missing in `Start()`. Suggested tag cause of duplicated enemies have different name. So when they have same tag, no need to worry about same name. You need to tag the object and then duplicate or apply in prefab. When this should solve the issue if you implement right, I suggest you to post another question clarifying "what if I wanted to add a number of how many enemies I want to destroy rather than copy and pasting below the code and renaming it" if you think I got it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it's still not working even though I did exactly what you told me to do. I will try and post another question. Thank you :)